# Unable to update user profile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, fetch

After user signup, I could't update user profile. However, the update works fine in postman. The issue seems to be coming from the frontend. I got the following error message

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\OcheEmmy\Desktop\investment_project\invest_back\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
    at parse (C:\Users\OcheEmmy\Desktop\investment_project\invest_back\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
    at C:\Users\OcheEmmy\Desktop\investment_project\invest_back\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\OcheEmmy\Desktop\investment_project\invest_back\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\OcheEmmy\Desktop\investment_project\invest_back\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\OcheEmmy\Desktop\investment_project\invest_back\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Backend Code

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Photo could not be uploaded'
            });
        }
        let user = req.profile;
        user = _.extend(user, fields);

        if (files.photo) {
            if (files.photo.size > 10000000) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: 'Image should be less than 1mb'
                });
            }
            user.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
            user.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;

            user.save((err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        error: 'You are not authorized to perform this action'
                    });
                }
                user.hashed_password = undefined;
                user.salt = undefined;
                res.json(user);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Here is the action code at the frontend

```
export const update = (userId, token, user) => {

    return fetch(`${API}/user/${userId}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            "Content-Type": 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: user

        /* body: JSON.stringify(user) */
    })
    .then(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};


export const updateUser = (user, next) => {
    if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
        if(localStorage.getItem('jwt')){
            let auth = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jwt"));
            auth.user = user;
            localStorage.setItem("jwt", JSON.stringify(auth));
            next();
        }
    }
};
```

If I use body: JSON.stringify(user) instaed of body: user, the network view will  be showing pending
[image]

Fronend code

```
const UserProfileUpdate = ({match}) => {
   const [values, setValues] = useState({
       
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        email: '',
        photo: '',
        about: '',
        error: false,
        success: false,
        userData: ''
    });

    const {about,userData, photo, firstname, lastname, email,  error, success} = values;
 
    const {user: { _id }} = isAuthenticated();
    const token = isAuthenticated().token;

    const init = userId => {
       //console.log(userId);
       read(userId, token).then(data => {
           if(data.error){
               setValues({...values, error: true})
           } else {
               setValues({
                ...values,
                firstname: data.firstname,
                lastname: data.lastname,
                email: data.email,
                photo: data.photo,
                
                about: data.about
            })
           }
       })
    }; 

    useEffect(() => {
        init(match.params.userId);
    }, []); 

    const handleChange = name => e => {
        /* console.log(e.target.value); */
        const value = name === 'photo' ? e.target.files[0] : e.target.value;
        let userFormData = new FormData();
        userFormData.set(name, value);
        setValues({ ...values, [name]: value, userData: userFormData, error: false, success: false });
    };

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //let userData = { username, firstname, lastname, email, photo, dailingCode, phonenumber, howdidyouknowaboutus, about, password };
        update(match.params.userId, token, userData /* { username, firstname, lastname, email, photo, dailingCode, phonenumber, howdidyouknowaboutus, about, password } */).then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                console.log(data.error);
                //alert(data.error);
            } else {
                updateUser(data, () => {
                    setValues({
                        ...values,
                       
                        firstname: data.firstname,
                        lastname: data.lastname,
                        email: data.email,
                        password: '',
                        
                        about: data.about,
                        success: true
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    };

    const redirectUser = (success) => {
        if(success){
            return <Redirect to={`/dashboard/${_id}/`}/>
        }
    }
```

I will really need your help. Thank you

Comment: Does your backend expect the body of the request to be JSON or [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)? The `Content-Type` header in your request is set to 'application/json', but the body appears to be `FormData`.

Comment: Thank you @Calvin. I removed the Content-Type header to enable the formData be render to backend. However, it is still showing pending in the network capture

Comment: Is your backend set up to send a response if `files.photo` does not evaluate to true?

Comment: @Calvin, yes. See the backend code above.

Using form in postman, it works fine

Comment: Would you mind adding an else statement to `if (files.photos)` that does `res.status(400).json({ message: "Missing files.photos" });` and see if you get a response? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with `formidable`.

Comment: Thank you @Calvin. You open my eye to the issue. I forget to set form.keepExtensions = true at the backend

It is now working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

set form.keepExtensions = true; at the backend

remove "content-Type": "applications/json" because formData is expected at the backend.

Thank you @Calvin. You really gave me a better debugging steps.